# Tricky Channel Entries Loop with Category Conditionals

Tags: channel-entries, categories, conditionals

I'd like to return entries from a specific channel, but what i'd like to do is ONLY show entries from a child category first, but if there are none, then show entries from the child's parent category.

Is this possible?

Comment: At the point in your template where you want to loop through the entries, do you already have BOTH the child and parent category IDs? E.g., hard-coded, or via an embed variable?

Comment: The approach in @RobsonSobral's answer is a good/simple one--he accounts for the case where you know only the child category ID.

Answer (score 2):

Put your loop on a embed and call it at this way:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="news" limit="1" category="X"}
    {if no_results}
        {exp:query
            sql="SELECT parent_id
                FROM exp_categories
                WHERE cat_id = X"
        }
            {embed="pages/.category_loop" cat_id="{parent_id}"}
        {/exp:query}
    {/if}
        {embed="pages/.category_loop" cat_id="X"}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```